# Getting UnsafeBufferPointer from ObjC

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers

In my ObjC-Swift bridging I currently use

```
- (double*)vector {
  return (double*)self.ndArray->vector();
}

- (long) size {
  return self.ndArray->size();
}
```

to create an array in Swift like

```
let p = vector.vector()
let s = vector.size()
let a = Array<Double>(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: p, count: s))
```

Would it be possible to get this directly from ObjC like

```
let a = Array<Double>(vector.readyPackedPointer())
```

?

Comment: A C pointer does not contain any information about the size of the pointed-to memory region, so you'll always have to pass both pointer and count.

Comment: @MartinR I feared so. ObjC is more C than Obj in that case then :-( Make it an answer...

Comment: Done. – But perhaps I am overlooking something and someone comes with a better idea ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C pointer does not contain any information about the size of the pointed-to memory region, so you'll always have to pass both pointer and count
from (Objective-)C to Swift. You could pass a `struct` containing both
pointer and count to save a function call.